# Implementing a for loop login in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, oracle

```
FOR deposit_indx IN 1..deposit_table_obj.COUNT
    LOOP     
      FOR i IN 1..category_table_obj.COUNT LOOP
        IF(deposit_table_obj(deposit_indx).borrower_category_code IS NULL
          OR deposit_table_obj(deposit_indx).sector_code IS NULL
          OR deposit_table_obj(deposit_indx).sub_sector_code IS NULL) 
        THEN
          excludeAcct := 1;                                
          EXIT;
        ELSIF(INSTR(category_table_obj(i).borrowercat_code, deposit_table_obj(deposit_indx).borrower_category_code) > 0
          AND INSTR(category_table_obj(i).sector_code, deposit_table_obj(deposit_indx).sector_code) > 0
          AND INSTR(category_table_obj(i).sub_sector_code, deposit_table_obj(deposit_indx).sub_sector_code) > 0) 
        THEN
          excludeAcct := 0;
          EXIT;        
        ELSE
          excludeAcct := 1;                                
        END IF;
      END LOOP;

      IF(excludeAcct = 1) THEN
        exclusion_table_obj.EXTEND;
        exclusion_table_obj(ex_indx).acid        :=  deposit_table_obj(deposit_indx).acid;
        exclusion_table_obj(ex_indx).balance     :=  deposit_table_obj(deposit_indx).balance;
        exclusion_table_obj(ex_indx).rep_date    :=  deposit_table_obj(deposit_indx).rep_date;
        ex_indx := ex_indx + 1;     
        excludeAcct := 0;                                                  
      END IF;

    END LOOP;
```

I'm trying to implement this section of the query into SQL SERVER. I'm planning to do a  select count(*) from deposite_table and select count(*) from category_table to use in the while loop condition or should I use a cursor? Also, the tables are gonna be temporary tables deposit_table and category_table and called from a stored procedure.

Comment: Cursors and while loops are almost always misused in SQL (Server), in my experience (especially to perform a count of rows). Sample data and expected results will be really useful here as I doubt you need a loop mechanic at all.

Comment: I think this could be written as an INSERT query but don't know your DB well enough to do it.

Comment: You have to start thinking of data as a set and not individual rows. When modifying data ask what you need to do to an entire column, not an individual row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, I don't think you need a cursor or loops. SQL just does that sort of stuff for you if you know how to ask it.

As far as I can tell your code inserts rows into exclusion_table_obj under certain conditions, so I think it would become an INSERT statement something like this:

```
INSERT INTO exclusion_table_obj(acid, balance, rep_date)
SELECT d.acid, d.balance, d.rep_date
FROM deposit_table_obj d
WHERE d.borrower_category_code IS NULL OR d.sector_code IS NULL OR d.sub_sector_code IS NULL
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM category_table_obj c
               WHERE c.borrowercat_code = d.borrower_category_code
               AND c.sector_code = d.sector_code
               AND c.sub_sector_code = d.sub_sector_code)
```